# Default Loop Iteration Scheduling in OpenMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I used the following statement from OpenMP:

```
omp_set_num_threads(6);
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < NUMS; ++i){
    printf("id is %3d   thread is %d\n",i, omp_get_thread_num());
}
```

I found out (in a blog post): each thread will be evenly allocated iterations, and, when the number of threads is not divisible by the number of iterations, it will be rounded up.

Well, I first set `NUMS=17`, the result is as follows:

```
id is  12   thread is 4
id is  13   thread is 4
id is  14   thread is 4
id is   9   thread is 3
id is  10   thread is 3
id is  11   thread is 3
id is   0   thread is 0
id is   1   thread is 0
id is   2   thread is 0
id is   6   thread is 2
id is   7   thread is 2
id is   8   thread is 2
id is  15   thread is 5
id is  16   thread is 5
id is   3   thread is 1
id is   4   thread is 1
id is   5   thread is 1
```

As can be seen, \lceil 17/6 \rceil = 3 (round up, forgive me, I don't know how to insert Latex formulas), the result is as expected.

However, if I set `NUMS=19`, according to rounding up 19/6 = 4, each thread should be allocated 4 iterations, however:

```
id is   0   thread is 0
id is   1   thread is 0
id is   2   thread is 0
id is   3   thread is 0
id is  10   thread is 3
id is  11   thread is 3
id is  12   thread is 3
id is   7   thread is 2
id is   8   thread is 2
id is   9   thread is 2
id is  13   thread is 4
id is  14   thread is 4
id is  15   thread is 4
id is   4   thread is 1
id is   5   thread is 1
id is   6   thread is 1
id is  16   thread is 5
id is  17   thread is 5
id is  18   thread is 5
```

As you can see, only the first one is assigned 4 iterations.

So I can't figure it out now, what exactly is the reason for this? What exactly is OpenMP's default thread scheduling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarising all the comments to create an answer (so thanks to all who commented).

First, what the standard says/requires :-

- It says **nothing** about which schedule should be used when it is unspecified.
- `schedule(static)` with no chunk_size is only specified as allocating "approximately equal" numbers of iterations to each available thread.

Second, what happens in reality at present :-

- Compilers default to using `schedule(static)` when no schedule is specified. (Though `schedule(nonmonotonic:dynamic)` might, now, be a better choice.)
- At least the LLVM OpenMP runtime allocates iterations to threads as this Python code shows (the critical part is `myCount`, the rest is just to test it and show your test cases).

  ```
  #
  # Show number of iterations allocated to each thread
  # by schedule(static) in the LLVM runtime
  #

   def myCount(me, numThreads, total):
       base = total // numThreads
       remainder = total % numThreads
       return base+1 if me < remainder else base

   def test(numThreads, total):
       print("Threads: ",numThreads, " Iterations: ",total)
       allocated = 0
       for thread in range(0,numThreads):
           mine = myCount(thread,numThreads,total)
           allocated += mine
           print (thread, ": ", mine)
       if allocated != total:
           print ("***ERROR*** ", allocated," allocated, ", total," requested")
   test(6,17)
   test(6,19)
  ```

If you run that you can see the result for your two test cases:-

```
% python3 static.py 
Threads:  6  Iterations:  17
0 :  3
1 :  3
2 :  3
3 :  3
4 :  3
5 :  2
Threads:  6  Iterations:  19
0 :  4
1 :  3
2 :  3
3 :  3
4 :  3
5 :  3
```

If you want to get into the full horror of loop scheduling, there is a whole chapter on this in "[High Performance Parallel Runtimes -- Design and Implementation](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110632729/html)"

p.s. It's worth noting that the schedule shown above cannot be explicitly requested by setting a `block_size` on a static schedule, since the standard does not then allow the remainder iterations to be split up as they are here. (E.g. If we try to allocate 10 iterations to 4 threads, if we set `block_size(2)` we'd get (4,2,2,2) whereas if we set it to 3 we'd get (3,3,3,1), whereas the scheme above gives (3,3,2,2), which has imbalance of 1 whereas the explicit schemes each have imbalance of 2).